# Best way to achieve feature flag based routing in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I would like to set up an infrastructure that enables easy experimentation in the production environment for developers in my team.

For example, let's assume that I have a HTML page that lists purchases for on online retail shop. The production version is implemented using React, but we would like to test out some alternative implementations, for example one written in Vue.js, and the other one that is not JS based and instead uses backend rendering.

In this scenario, I would like to flip a feature flag for all the developers who are working on the Vue.js implementation to see the Vue.js page, and for the backend rendering team to see their implementation.

In Kubernetes, each implementation would be a different pod/replication set/service.

[image]

What is the best pattern to implement the above routing scheme in Kubernetes? Is [Istio based intelligent HTTP header based routing](https://istio.io/docs/guides/intelligent-routing.html) a good candidate for this task?

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, more clean way is to use different path/FQDN for each type of backend and manage all of them by any ingress controller. At least it will able your developers to access the new version without customization of requests.

But, if you want to use a header as a feature flag and manage routing based on it, then yes, content [based routing in Istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing.html#content-based-routing) will be OK, I think.